# On the closed subring of valuation rings

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, fields, local-rings, valuation-theory, valuation-rings

Let $(K,v)$ be a (not necessarily discrete) valued field of characteristic $p$ with valuation ring $\mathcal{O}$ and residue field $k$. We endow $K$ and $\mathcal{O}$ with the valuation topology. Suppose that $R$ is a proper subring of $\mathcal{O}$, satisfying the following conditions:

1. $R$ is a closed local subring of $\mathcal{O}$;
2. the residue field of $R$ is $k$;
3. the fraction field of $R$ is $K$.

Then to what extent does $ R$ control $K$? For example, does the closeness of $R$ imply the completeness of $K$, under certain hypotheses on $K$ and $R$?

I'm unaware of any result of this kind, so I cannot provide more information.